# Objective C keypath to get all artists from iTunes

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate, enumeration, key-value-coding

I'm using key-value-coding to get all the artists from iTunes:

```
[self.iTunes valueForKeyPath:@"sources.@distinctUnionOfArrays.playlists.@distinctUnionOfArrays.tracks.artist"];
```

Now, this works fine. 
This is very efficient. I would also like to do the same with the album.

```
[self.iTunes valueForKeyPath:@"sources.@distinctUnionOfArrays.playlists.@distinctUnionOfArrays.tracks.album"];
```

The problem here is, that there are multiple albums with the same name, but not necessarily of the same artist. Is there a way to get a song of each album, so I can find out what artists it is, and also get the cover of it?
I know there is NSPredicate, but this is very slow.

The specific code is not important, I only need the key-value coding part.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*This is not a complete answer.*

For the benefit of folks like me who didn't originally know where this was documented: You have to be on a Mac with iTunes installed, and then run the command

```
sdef /Applications/iTunes.app | sdp -fh --basename iTunes
```

which will magically create `iTunes.h` in your current working directory. Then you can trawl through `iTunes.h` to see how the API looks. It doesn't seem to be officially documented in the Mac Developer Library or anything.

Each `iTunesTrack` has an `artist` property in addition to the `album` property, so I would think that all you really want to do is return an array of unique tuples `(album, artist)`.

Okay, so how can we get an array of tuples out of a single KVC query? We'd like to write something like `sources.@distinctUnionOfArrays.playlists.@distinctUnionOfArrays.tracks.albumAndArtist` and have that return something like an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`, for example `@[ @{ @"Help!", @"The Beatles" }, @{ @"No!", @"They Might Be Giants" }, ... ]`

**EDIT** ughoavgfhw suggested the next step in a comment: You could use a category to define `albumAndArtist` like so:

```
@interface iTunesTrack (albumAndArtist)
@property (readonly) NSDictionary *albumAndArtist;
@end

@implementation iTunesTrack (albumAndArtist)
-(NSDictionary *) albumAndArtist
{
    return @{ @"album":self.album, @"artist":self.artist };
}
@end
```

And now you can write the line we were trying to write:

```
[self.iTunes valueForKeyPath:@"sources.@distinctUnionOfArrays.playlists.@distinctUnionOfArrays.tracks.albumAndArtist"];
```

This should give you an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`, which is basically what you wanted. Mind you, I haven't tested this code or anything!

Comment: You could use a category to define an `albumAndArtist` property which returns the dictionary, then use that property with KVC to get all of the different pairs.

Comment: You guys are geniuses! The only thing I had to change was the category class. iTunesTrack is not a real class. I had to do it with SBObject. But the rest worked like a charm, thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry, I still have a question. It works, but unfortunately it's still a lot slower then using a built in property. Can you tell why?

Comment: I tried returning for example only the artists-string, which was still very very slow...

-(NSString *) albumAndArtist
{
    return [(ITunesFileTrack *)self album];
}

Comment: Re "slower than builtin property": Well, constructing a new NSDictionary is slow, compared to returning an existing NSString.  Re "slower than returning just the artist": I would expect `[self album]` to be a lot faster than `@{ ... }`, but it *is* still doing that one extra method dispatch. I'd naively expect `albumAndArtist { return [self album]; }` to be twice as slow as `album`, because there are twice as many method dispatches. If you really need it to be blazing fast, maybe see http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/performance-comparisons-of-common-operations.html

Comment: I still don't get how the property album can be lightning fast, and a simple albumAndArtist { return [self album]; } property can be very very very slow, but I decided to let it go :)

Answer (score 1):

@Ilija: If you post to say you've let it go, then you haven't really let it go yet. ;)  Let me see if I can clarify [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359631/objective-c-keypath/12501168#comment16850416_12501168):

```
-(NSString *) album
{
    return self->album;
}

-(NSDictionary *) albumAndArtist
{
    return @{ @"album":self.album, @"artist":self.artist };
}
```

The `album` method above is what the Objective-C compiler will generate for you automatically.* The `albumAndArtist` method is what I suggested in my answer to your original question. Now, if you ask Clang to lower these two methods to C (`clang -rewrite-objc test.m -o test.cc`), you get something like this:

```
static NSDictionary * _I_iTunesTrack_albumAndArtist_albumAndArtist(iTunesTrack * self, SEL _cmd) {
    return ((NSDictionary *(*)(id, SEL, const id *, const id *, NSUInteger))(void *)
    objc_msgSend)(objc_getClass("NSDictionary"), sel_registerName("dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:"),
    (const id *)__NSContainer_literal(2U, ((NSString *(*)(id, SEL))(void *)objc_msgSend)
    ((id)self, sel_registerName("album")), ((NSString *(*)(id, SEL))(void *)objc_msgSend)
    ((id)self, sel_registerName("artist"))).arr, (const id *)__NSContainer_literal(2U,
    (NSString *)&__NSConstantStringImpl_test_m_0, (NSString *)&__NSConstantStringImpl_test_m_1).arr, 2U);
}
```

or, in human terms,

```
-(NSDictionary *) albumAndArtist
{
    id album = objc_msgSend(self, sel_registerName("album"));
    id artist = objc_msgSend(self, sel_registerName("artist"));
    id *values = calloc(2, sizeof(id)); values[0] = album; values[1] = artist;
    id *keys = calloc(2, sizeof(id)); keys[0] = @"album"; keys[1] = @"artist";
    Class dict_class = objc_getClass("NSDictionary");
    id result = objc_msgSend(dict_class, sel_registerName("dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:"), values, keys, 2);
    free(values); free(keys);
    return result;
}
```

Check it out: three `sel_registerName`s, one `objc_getClass`, three `objc_msgSend`s, two `calloc`s, and two `free`s. That's pretty inefficient, compared to the compiler-generated `album` method.

> Technically, the compiler-generated `album` method looks like this:
>
> ```
> -(NSString *) album
> {
>     return objc_getProperty(self, _cmd,
>         __OFFSETOFIVAR__(struct iTunesTrack, album), /*atomic*/ YES);
> }
> ```
>
> but that's only because it wasn't originally declared as `nonatomic`. For the meaning of `objc_getProperty`, see [here](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/10/memory-and-thread-safe-custom-property.html); but basically, it's faster than an `objc_msgSend` would have been.)

So clearly `albumAndArtist` is going to be much slower than `album`, because of all that extra work it's doing. But — you ask — what if we get rid of all that work and just return `self.album`? Well, the generated code is still hairier than what the compiler generated for the `album` getter:

```
-(NSString *) albumAndArtist_stripped_down
{
    // return self.album;
    return objc_msgSend(self, sel_registerName("album"));
}
```

When your program calls `myTrack.album`, it invokes `objc_msgSend` once to figure out that it should call the `album` method, and then inside `album` it invokes `objc_getProperty`. That's two calls. (Three if you count `selector_registerName("album")`.)

When your program calls `myTrack.albumAndArtist_stripped_down`, it invokes `objc_msgSend` once to figure out that it should call the `albumAndArtist_stripped_down` method, and then *that* calls `objc_msgSend` a second time, and then *that* calls `objc_getProperty`. That's three calls. (Five if you count `selector_registerName`.)

So it makes sense to me that `albumAndArtist_stripped_down` should be about twice as slow (or 5/3 as slow) as `album` by itself.

And as for the original `albumAndArtist`, just by counting the function calls, I'd expect it to be about five times as slow as `album`... but of course it'll be *much* slower than that, because it's doing at least three memory allocations, whereas `album` isn't doing any. Memory allocation and cleanup is *very* expensive, because `malloc` is a complicated algorithm in its own right.

I hope this clears up the issue for you. :)

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for your explanation!
I wouldn't have thought it made that much of a difference.
Cleared thing up for me :)

Comment: After some programming experience I realize what was really going on at this time. Actually, this really has very little to do with nonatomic methods, but rather with AppleScript. Scripting Bridge automatically makes calls to AppleScript when necessary, which are very expensive. There are methods in `SBElementArray` which wrap up these calls, so if you want every track of the library, it will deliver them all at once. However, if you iterate through the array yourself, it will have to make a call for every single object. Just in case you were wondering.